# Tomcat: disbale enable datasource

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, datasource

Is it possible to enable and disable a datasource in Tomcat? I have configured a datasource the the context.xml file. The datasource is working, but from admin persective, I need to be able to stop this dataource without stopping the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment it in context.xml but i think you require app reboot.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Only with full appservers as JBoss or Weblogic you are able to stop/start the datasource individually.